# Не открывается ссылка через input

Tags: python, input, webbrowser

Создаю код и столкнулся с проблемой, мне нужно чтобы с input значение вставлялось в код куда нужно вставлять ссылку. Объяснить сложно, но думаю поймете.

Есть вот такой простой код:

```
import webbrowser

s = input("Ссылка на ролик:")
webbrowser.open("{s}", new=2)
```

Вставляю я значит туда ссылку, открывается браузер, открывается вкладка, но не с ссылкой, которую я вставил, а вот с такой вот штукой:       `http://%7Bs%7D/`

И так с любым текстом или ссылкой которую вставлю.

Мне нужно вставлять ссылки с ютуба.

Comment: Замените `"{s}"` на `s`

Answer (score 0):

Вот правильній код:

```
import webbrowser
s = input()
webbrowser.open(url=s, new=2)
```

Comment: или без url= , на твое усмотрение